# GPU accelarated browser?

Tags: raspbian, chromium

Currently I'm running Raspbian but I'm willing to install any version of Linux. I just need the Pi as a dedicated browser opening one internal site with images. Works great with Midori and Chromium but image transitions are very sluggish.

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing with this and found the best I could get was Firefox for Pi.
`apt-get` the following:

- `iceweasel` this is the browser
- `browser-plugin-gnash` this is for some limited video like YouTube

The few sites I loaded perform well. Video is pretty bad, but at low settings on the quality and some higher settings on the Pi it's not too bad. For larger sites it can be a bit sluggish. I was running at pretty much every setting and a memory split of up to 256. It won't likely stream movies or long YouTube videos, but for checking mail and general surfing it can support much more then the stock browsers.

Comment: If you want to stream youtube video, use the GPU accelerated `omxplayer` with `yt` -- plays high-res HD content flawlessly, no glitches, delays, etc.  The same principle (buffering/converting the stream to a file and passing the file to oxmplayer, which is what I think yt does) should be applicable to any source, but you would need to set that part up yourself.

Comment: I'm not too concerned with Video right now since I know omxplayer had very nice hardware accelation. I'm just looking for some sort of web hardware accelation. I have seen QT5 webview but it's not easy to get it to work.